# How to test jobs which were scheduled (each one min, cron "* * * * *"), but not wait "real" one minute (rufus-scheduler vs virtual time)?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, time, rufus-scheduler

`rufus-scheduler` lib allows us to schedule tasks
https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

```rb
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.cron '* * * * *' do
  # do something every minute
end
```

In fact, when you want to test your app on top of `rufus-scheduler` you will need to sleep `real 1 min` which is too much for typical tests.

For example, in `Reactor(Java)` they provide `StepVerifier.withVirtualTime` in order to avoid long-running tests.`:

- https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_manipulating_time
- https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher#3-testing-time-based-publishers
- RxJava - https://medium.com/@vanniktech/taking-control-of-the-time-when-testing-rxjava-code-91b2e5e88bdf

Are there any options for time manipulation within tests for `rufus-scheduler` or `Ruby` itself?

**Current solution**

`rufus-scheduler` has type `in`, thus for verification of app skeleton I'm using `in=0.001s` and `sleep 0.4`.

Yes, it takes half-of a second in the test but this is much better than 1 minute.

Comment: I would argue that you should not test the code in your example because it doesn't anything that is specific to your app. It only tests the scheduler and the scheduler has its own tests. Only test your own code.

Comment: @spickermann according to the book `"Growing Object-Oriented Software, Guided by Tests"`
 it's better to build a skeleton for E2E testing of your app. 
I like their main idea about the skeleton, however I don't like their code examples as its too procedural, lot of static and ugly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at

- https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop
- https://andycroll.com/ruby/replace-timecop-with-rails-time-helpers-in-rspec/

or other "time travel" tools.

I second @spickermann on "only test your own code".